# Spring Reactive in void methods

Tags: spring-boot, reactive

I am facing difficulties in understand reactive stream principles, and getting problem with a simple solution that is easy solved by java 8 streams.
I would like to do this:

```
class service{
public void add(List<Car> cars){
 cars.parallelStream.forEach(car -> repo.add(car));
}
```

using Spring Reactor implementation.
I saw many examples on internet but usually with object mapping or something like this.

Comment: Are you asking how do `cars.parallelStream.forEach(car -> repo.add(car))` using Rx?

Comment: Yes Enigmativy. But spring boot 2 uses Reactor, not rxjava

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't know it. Can only help with Rx.

Answer (score 2):

Spring reactor has 2 types of publishers:

1. Mono-contains 0(empty) or 1 element in the stream.
2. Flux-contains 0-N elements in the stream.

Since you get a list of Car objects, we have to use Flux publisher.

To create a publisher having the elements contained in the list, you have to do the following:

```
Flux.fromIterable(cars);
```

This gives you a publisher which emits objects of the Car.

Another point is that, since its spring reactor now, you have to change the return type of service as well as repository method to `Mono<Void>` and the repository must extend the reactive repository (as per the database you are using)

Now to add the objects in repository, you would have to do the following:

```
Flux.fromIterable(cars)
.flatMap(car->repo.add(car));
```

Using the flatMap operator you make the async repo calls. To know what goes inside flatMap, go [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).
Hope this gives you some idea ok how to use spring reactor.